# something other than gembox.spreadsheet with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation, gembox-spreadsheet

Had a wee go at using gembox.spreadsheet to read an excel doc from asp.net, nice package but too expensive

Anyone know of any other software like that that isn't expensive and does the same job?

Comment: There are plenty of free and not free solutions for reading xls for .net, depends a lot on the level of complexity you need to manipulate sheets. Can you update the question so you can be pointed in the right direction?

Comment: @alexb well I have large amounts of data to upload from the excel sheet, and although the free version of gembox.spreadsheet is perfect (and simple to use) it just isn't enough. I need to be able to read more rows and worksheets and unfortunately the full version is too expensive for me to purchase.  All I am looking to do is read  excel documents from asp.net dynamic data project.

Comment: did you check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp). nothing usefull?